# Why does CuteEditor's toolbar has trasparent background in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, transparency, wysiwyg, toolbar, cuteeditor

I am using cute editor in my asp.net website. Problem is the toolbar has transparent background which makes it difficult to see the buttons clearly in Firefox.
And this problem is not with IE.
How do I fix this problem? 've tried BackColor tag of cutesoft, but transparency still stays.

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with **ThemeType**. I removed it and the transparency issue has gone with it.